# HTML5 mobile app - is it possible to auto update without a pull from the market

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile

I'm doing a research to find if there're any good ways of having an HTML5 application to do a self update. Basically my logic is that the app would check for available update and then download it directly. My idea is to be able to update both existing CSS, HTML and images, including downloading new or updating existing files.

I want to be able to tell the user that the application is being updated, without them having to do it through the market. I'm aware that Android market (I'm not sure about the Apple store unfortunatelly) lets you allow auto-update for specific apps. I could also notify the user in-app that their version is outdated. This is all good, but I want to know if there's any specific technique for this to be automated.

Please advise :)

Thank you,
Andriyan Ivanov

Comment: Apple used to deny apps that had auto update ability, but that may have changed.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google Play policy:

```
An app downloaded from Google Play may not modify, replace or update its own APK binary code using any method other than Google Play's update mechanism.
```

Source: http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html

So it means you can't  self-update your apk's content. You need to upload updated apk to Google Play to update your app.